# How can I tether my phone's internet with bluetooth through the terminal after pairing the devices?

Tags: networking, command-line, bash, bluetooth, tethering

I have paired my phone to my laptop with bluetooth using the below commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bluetooth bluez bluez-tools rfkill
rfkill unblock bluetooth
bluetoothctl
agent KeyboardOnly
default-agent
power on
scan on
pair <BT address>
trust <BT address>
connect <BT address>
```

What I want to know if there is a way to tether my phone's internet through terminal as well.

I can do it through ubuntu settings, but I want it done with terminal commands.

Can I do this? If so, how?

My ubuntu version is 18.04 if it helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548298/how-to-connect-to-the-internet-via-a-bluetooth-access-point-from-command-line).

```
# to list available connections
nmcli connection show

# to connect to uuid: 1
nmcli connection up "1"
```